# Multicoded values in SQL Server Analysis Service

Tags: ssas, mdx

[image]

I have a fact table where the some columns are having multicoded values. It means for some responses, I have multiple values so I added multiple rows for that, adding null values for the remaining columns.

When I retrieve the data through a MDX, it gives the result correctly, but there is a scneario (red one) where I need to retrieve the data based on a sample (condition) based on that filled null value column. So the answer is coming incorrectly for that.

Is there any way I can fix this through a structure change or with a mdx approach?

Comment: What is the correct result for the red sheet?

Comment: @MoazRub - Correct result should be the same as left one. As User 13 is having a value for Q01 (even in one row), he should be taken to the final result

Comment: Share your query that is resulting the red table